# ISO-8859-15 encoding with nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-15

We are experiencing a very anoying encoding problem which started with loopback but seems to be nodejs related.
Basically, we just finished developping an API with Loopback based upon an existing SQL_ASCII encoded postgresql database. Since the API has to be in UTF-8, we try to convert the data sent through our API routes to ISO-8859-15 in order to insert them correctly in our base.
No matter what iconv, utf8, iso-8859 etc. modules we tried, we couldn't get to pass ISO-8859-15 converted strings, we ended up with very strange stuff. For example :

```
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv; 
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1'); 
var label = iconv.convert("bébé").toString();
```

If we insert then the "label" into our database, we end up with someting like that = **"bï¿½bï¿½"** !

So we just tried to look directly in the Terminal how it behaved with a basic nodejs application (without loopback or any other framework) but it didn't turn out to be better.
Once the Terminal encoding set up to "ISO Latin 1", the following code :

```
console.log('bébé');
```

Was displayed this way in the Terminal :

```
bÃ©bÃ©
```

As if nodejs was completely unable to handle ISO-8859 strings.
Are we missing something there ?
Are we doomed to use UTF-8 string in order to make this work ?